# How do I change the input of a script to be the first argument on the CLI?

Tags: scripting, rename

I have a script called rename, and where it states `./wid_*.jil` I want to be able to enter that information from the command line while executing the script.

```
for file in ./wid_*.jil
do
    mv -i "${file}" "${file/orig/update}"
done
```

On the command line I would like to be able to enter

```
[user@location dir1]$ rename dir2/
```

The script would then look in `dir2/` and rename all files with `orig` in their name to `update`.

I'm very new to unix/linux so I apologize if my terminology is off, or if my description is poor.

Comment: Note that `rename` might be a pre-existing command on some systems.

Comment: If variable length arguments (multiple directories), you can use either `$@` or `$*` (see [this post for the distinction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12316565/868044)). If just one then `$1` will get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1 will be the first argument of your bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="$1"

echo "$directory"
```

You can also perform some checks, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="$1"

[ -z "$directory" ] && echo "Please provide a directory" && exit 1
[ ! -d "$directory" ] && echo "Directory not found" && exit 2

for file in "$directory"/wid_*.jil
do
    mv -i "${file}" "${file/orig/update}"
done
```

Comment: Nitpick: What if `$directory` contains the string `orig`?

Comment: @Kusalananda - yeah I don't usually construct my loops this way.  In this case you can use basename to separate out the file name from the directory.  There might be more intelligent bash string replacement techniques, but I don't know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

The shell stores all command line arguments in what's called the *positional parameters*, `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc.

A simple script that renames all files matching `wid_*.jil` in a directory by replacing the string `orig` with `update` in the filename, might look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

dir="$1"

if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
  printf 'No such directory: %s\n' "$dir" >&2
  exit 1
fi

for filepath in "$dir"/wid_*.jil; do
  filename="$( basename "$filepath" | sed 's/orig/update/g' )"
  mv -i "$filepath" "$dir/$filename"
done
```

Or, without using external utilities, with `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$1"

if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
  printf 'No such directory: %s\n' "$dir" >&2
  exit 1
fi

for filepath in "$dir"/wid_*.jil; do
  filename="${filepath##*/}"
  filename="${filename//orig/update}"

  mv -i "$filepath" "$dir/$filename"
done
```